# What do I need to know in order for a US citizen to open a custodian brokerage account in Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, financial-literacy

I need to open custodian brokerage accounts for my 2 Canadian grandchildren, ages 16 and 13. As a US citizen, I am willing to tie them to a US savings account in USD. What is the best way to do that with little entanglements in the exchange rate and IRS potential problems?

Answer (score -1):

Reading and writing. Talking and listening also helps. See, you contact the broker an they will send you a lot of paperwork that explains it all, but you have to read it. Then you have to fill it out. Any detail questions they will answer - which helps to talk to them, i.e. on a phone.

Procedures may be broker dependent, so - you really need to talk to the specific broker.

Comment: The OP is not asking about the procedures at a specific broker. They are asking about how to about exchange rate and tax issues. You might try your own snippy advice about reading.